# count string occurrences across multiple column sql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

How can I count total no. of $ signs present in a table? Simple select query will not work in this case. How should I edit my select query to count string occurrences across multiple columns in a table.

```
c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5|
$  |    |    | $  |   |  
   | $  |  $ | $  |   |   
   |    |    |    |   |
$  |    |    |    |   |
```

($ signs are present randomly in the table in any column)
I tried to get the count through regex but it always return no. of rows in which $ is present, not the number of $.

Comment: No regular expressions are needed. Is this about PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Comment: yes, postgresSQL or mysql queries are welcome.

Comment: You are trying to pivot the data. MySQL does not have a pivot function. You will have to use case statement with count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `case` inside count to count occurrence of `$` in your columns

```
select 
  count(case when c1 = '$' then 1 else null end) 
+ count(case when c2 = '$' then 1 else null end)
+ count(case when c3 = '$' then 1 else null end) 
+ count(case when c4 = '$' then 1 else null end) 
+ count(case when c5 = '$' then 1 else null end) cnt
from your_table
```

[Demo Mysql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4631db/1)

[Demo Postgre](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2846f/2)

Comment: M khalid Junaid, it worked, thanks! :)